# Jquery flippy plugin multi content

Tags: javascript, jquery, flippy

**HTML :**

```
 <div class ="cards">
      <span id="cardtitle">
      </span>
      <span id="cardinfo">
      </span>
    </div>
```

**J-QUERY:**

```
function build() {
  var content1 = "Coolio";
  var content2 = "Coolio";
  $(".cards").flippy({
    color_target: "#F8F8F8",
    duration: "500",
    verso: $("#cardtitle").text(content1)
    // another instance of verso here to add content2
});
}
```

I am using [this](http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/) jquery plugin for flip effect. My question is how do I achieve multiple contents. At the moment the plug only accepts 1 content.

Comment: Could you carify what you mean by multiple content? In the demo a button is clicked an the image is flipped in a certain direction (directions:left, right, top. bottom, revert) Do you mean that clicking twice on left should first show one image (cat) and the second click shows the next image (dog)?

Comment: No what I mean is if a button is clicked a div should appear with the apropiate content. Each div has 2 spans `cardtitle` and `cardinfo`. But currently the plugin allows for just 1 span. So the flipped div would say for exampled Card 1 - Go to jail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like the Developer has made it so you've got to recreate the instance of the flip each time you'd like to [apply new content](https://github.com/lepixel/flippy/blob/master/demo.js), so you've got to make that a little more generic within a `.click()` handler.

Dependant on the Button or Navigation you've clicked on, ask it to load the appropriate content that it's tagged too, example:

```
<div id="content-one" style="display: none;">
      Some first Example text
</div>

<div id="content-two" style="display: none;">
      Second Example Text
</div>

<input type="button" 
       class="updateflip" 
       value="Display Content One" 
       data-contenttext="content-one" />

<input type="button" 
      class="updateflip" 
      value="Display Content Two" 
      data-contenttext="content-two" />

<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.updateflip', function( event ) {
        $('.cards').flippy({
            color_target: "#F8F8F8",
            duration: "500",
            verso: $('#'+ $(this).data('contenttext') +'').text()
            //E.g. $('#content-one').text(); shows "Some first Example text"
        });
    });  
</script>
```

**Demo Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8TQFb/

Upon clicking a class of `.updateflip` it will look at it's `data-contenttext` attribute, which in turns points to an hidden `<div />` within the page, thus brings up the hidden text. You could apply this further with having different colours too within the `data-*` attribute:

```
<input type="button" 
      class="updateflip" 
      value="Display Content Two" 
      data-color-target="#f1f1f1"
      data-speed="2100"
      data-contenttext="content-two" />
```

And thus, pass these button specific related attributes into the `.updateflip` handler as well to create something like in the demo below:

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Hx5uQ/

[image]

Comment: @ MackieeE sorry mate I didn't fully understand your answer. I managed to make it work. See my answer. All it needed was a small tweak, perhaps I wasn't very clear with my question. In any case thanks mate.

Comment: No problem, apologies for the mis-understanding then!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i got it to work. The plugin does take multiple elements. It was a misunderstanding on my part.

```
var content1 = "Coolio";
var content2 = "Coolio";
$(".cards").flippy({
    color_target: "#F8F8F8",
    duration: "500",
    verso: '<span id="cardtitle">' + content1 
           + ' </span><span id="cardinfo"> ' + content2 + '</span>'
});
```

I changed:

- `verso: $("#cardtitle").text(content1)`
- to: `verso: '<span id="cardtitle">' + content1 + ' </span><span id="cardinfo"> ' + content2 + '</span>'`